# Почему не закрывается функция в блоке try excpept?[python]

Tags: python, try

```py
import math


# task_3
def pir_square():
    try:
        a = int(input("Введите длину основания: "))
        b = int(input("Введите наклонную высоту: "))
    except:
        print("\nВведите заново")
        pir_square()
        return
    else:
        return a ** 2 + 2 * a * math.sqrt(b * 2 - a ** 2 / 4)


def pir_perimeter():
    try:
        a = int(input("Введите длину основания: "))
        b = int(input("Введите наклонную высоту: "))
    except:
        print("\nВведите заново")
        pir_perimeter()
        return
    else:
        return 4 * (a + b)


def pir_volume():
    try:
        a = int(input("Введите длину основания: "))
        h = int(input("Введите высоту: "))
    except:
        print("\nВведите заново")
        pir_volume()
        return
    else:
        return 1 / 3 * h * a ** 2


def par_square():
    try:
        a, b, c = map(int, input("Введите стороны параллелепипеда через пробел: ").split())
        print(a)
    except:
        print("\nВведите заново")
        par_square()
        return
    else:
        return 2 * (a * b + a * c + b * c)


def par_perimetr():
    try:
        a, b, c = map(int, input("Введите стороны параллелепипеда через пробел: ").split())
    except:
        print("\nВведите заново")
        par_perimetr()
        return
    else:
        return 4 * (a + b + c)


def par_volume():
    try:
        a, b, c = map(int, input("Введите стороны параллелепипеда через пробел: ").split())
    except:
        print("\nВведите заново")
        par_volume()
        return
    else:
        return a * b * c


def main_choice(n):
    if n in (1, 2):
        return second_choice(n)
    else:
        main_choice(n)


def second_choice(n):
    try:
        m = int(input("\n1. Площадь\n"
                      "2. Перимет\n"
                      "3. Объем\n"
                      "Ввыберите формулу: "))
    except:
        print("\nВведите заново")
        second_choice(n)
        return
    else:
        if m in (1, 2, 3):
            formule = {"11": pir_square, "12": pir_perimeter, "13": pir_volume,
                       "21": par_square, "22": par_perimetr, "23": par_volume}
            return formule[f"{n}{m}"]()
        else:
            print("\nВведите заново")
            second_choice(n)
            return


def task_3():
    try:
        n = int(input("1. Правильная четырехугольная Пирамида\n"
                  "2. Параллелепипед\n"
                  "Выберите фигуру: "))
    except:
        print("\nВведите заново")
        task_3()
        return
    if n in (1, 2):
        return main_choice(n)
    else:
        print("\nВведите заново")
        task_3()
        return

print(task_3())
```

Я запрашиваю значения через консоль и при неправильном значении программа должна запросить еще раз, но она создает в памяти новую функцию и не завершает предыдущую. И в конце, если пользователь делал ошибки не выводит ответ, потому что он где-то теряется(как я понял).

Требуется любая помощь, можете не исправлять этот код, а показать наиболее чистое написание такого типа задач.

Просто изучаю try except else и  def.

Было бы здорово если дадите пару советов по коду, как сделать его лучше и укажите на ошибки по мимо помощи с вопросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем варианте используется *рекурсивный вызов функции* - функция вызывает сама себя. А результат теряется из-за того, что вы не никак не обрабатываете и не возвращаете результат рекурсивного вызова функции.
Обычно для такого рода задач используют бесконечный цикл `while True:` с выходом по `break` или `return`.
Также обратите внимание, что при некоторых числовых исходных данных может возникать ошибка в выражении `a ** 2 + 2 * a * math.sqrt(b * 2 - a ** 2 / 4)` - извлечение корня из отрицательного числа, что также приведет к повторному вводу данных. Это можно отдельно обработать.

```
import math


def pir_square():
    while True:
        try:
            a = int(input("Введите длину основания: "))
            b = int(input("Введите наклонную высоту: "))
            try:
                return a ** 2 + 2 * a * math.sqrt(b * 2 - a ** 2 / 4)
            except ValueError:
                print('\nОшибка при вычислении выражения (квадратный корень из отрицательного числа). Введите новые данные')
        except ValueError:
            print("\nВы ввели не число, введите заново")


print(pir_square())
```

```
Введите длину основания: десять

Вы ввели не число, введите заново
Введите длину основания: 10
Введите наклонную высоту: 10

Ошибка при вычислении выражения (квадратный корень из отрицательного числа). Введите новые данные
Введите длину основания: 10
Введите наклонную высоту: 20
177.45966692414834
```

Comment: Да, как не додумался до такого, спасибо большое.
Получается каждую функцию стоит обернуть в цикл while?
И вопрос такой странный у меня. 
Я создаю сейчас колесо(грубо говоря) или это нормальная практика?